# HDMI not detected after upgrade to 18.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, upgrade, hdmi

I upgraded my Asus n76vj from 18.04 to 18.10 and HDMI stopped working (it works on Windows 10).

Here are some info on my system:

```
$ lspci | grep -iE "display|vga|hdmi"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09) 
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 635M] (rev a1)
```

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 215mm
   1920x1080     60.01*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93    40.01  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
VGA-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

```
$ sudo lshw -C display
    *-display UNCLAIMED       
           description: VGA compatible controller
           product: GF108M [GeForce GT 635M]
           vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
           version: a1
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list
           configuration: latency=0
           resources: memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
      *-display
           description: VGA compatible controller
           product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
           vendor: Intel Corporation
           physical id: 2
           bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
           version: 09
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
           configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
           resources: irq:27 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

It feels like a driver problem, but last time I upgraded it, it took me one day to get rid of a black screen problem, so if anybody has another fix for this, it will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is secure boot off?

Comment: @Kulfy secure boot is off

Comment: Since your display is **Unclaimed** and I believe installing driver is best way to **claim** the device. So there is no other way.

Comment: For those that wonder, i just needed to upgrade the drivers.

Comment: Could you tell us how you did that in an answer? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was the obvious solution, as suggested by Kulfy: update the drivers.

`$ sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

and reboot.